# Abrir un archivo de otro directorio con C++ en GNU/Linux

Tags: c++, linux, unix

Mi intención es seleccionar un archivo de texto del directorio **texto/** pero al seleccionarlo me tira el error.

```
ifstream Archivo;
system("clear");
cout << "Elige el archivo que quieres leer" << endl;
system("cd texto/ && ls --color");
cout << "Abrir: ";
cin >> archivo_elegir;          
Archivo.open(archivo_elegir);
if(Archivo.fail()){
    cout << "Error al abrir el archivo." << endl;
    exit(1);
}
else{
    cout << "OK";
}                       
Archivo.close();
```

Si tuviera los txt en el mismo directorio del ejecutable y cambio la línea

```
system("cd text/ && ls --color");
```

por

```
system("ls --color");
```

el programa funciona.

Comment: estas cambiando de directorio con el comando system, a nivel SO pero en tu programa, al momento de abrir el archivo lo estas abriendo sin darle el path "texto/". Intenta con: "Archivo.open("texto/" + archivo_elegir".

Comment: Muchas gracias, con esto pude solucionar mi problema.

Comment: @EmilianoTorres dado que el comentario soluciona el problema te recomiendo ponerlo como respuesta para que posteriormente el autor pueda marcarla como válida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas cambiando de directorio con el comando system, a nivel SO pero en tu programa, al momento de abrir el archivo lo estas abriendo sin darle el path "texto/". Intenta con: "Archivo.open("texto/" + archivo_elegir".